# SQL statistical authorization

Tags: sql

I am trying to understand how statistical authorization works in SQL.

Comment: How are you defining "used in the aggregate"? What if you do `SELECT MAX(case when id=10 then salary end) WHERE id IN (1,2,3,10)`? Is this homework?

Comment: That edit made me Google it - [Question 4 here then.](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/spr01/a5.html)

Comment: Martin, I think I'm in the same class as this user. Kind of a shame, really. Question 4 from that page was given to us as part of our homework which, coincidentally, is due today.

Comment: Martin, really sorry for the late reply, and I appreciate your help

Comment: Abyss Knight, I have no idea what you are talking about. Kind of a shame? This is kind of impolite

Answer (score 1):

> The query result must be a single
>   aggregate value.

This means you may only use `SUM(salary)` or `COUNT(*)` in the select list. If the ID was included, the individual employees can be identified.

> At least 3 different tuples should be
>   used in the aggregate to produce each
>   query result

You can include a `HAVING` clause like this:

```
having count(distinct ID) >= 3
```

I don't understand the rest of the question.

Comment: Part 3 is presumably to stop you doing `SUM(salary) WHERE id IN (1,2,3,10)` then `SUM(salary) WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` to get the details for `10`